# How to check whether any column was changed in jqgrid row edit

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, inline-editing

I am having a requirement where during the edit process, if there column values are not changed, then I need to escape the save operation to the server.Some thing like a dirty check which will let me know whether any values was changed in the edit process of the jqGrid.

Comment: you can store the old value e a separete column